# Multiple Values for a property on a node - Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Can somebody please help me with Cypher code for following problem statement? My Dataset is as below

```
 Object, Size, Color 
 A,200,White
 A,300,Black
 A,200,Pink
 B,300,White
 B,300,Black
```

The expected output is two nodes A and B with two properties Size and Color but there should not be duplicate size being displayed. For Example Node A has 200 in White and Pink Color but Size property should be showing 200 only once i.e. (200,300) and Color property should be showing (White, Black, Pink).

This is what I have tried:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myfile.csv" AS nodeRecord 
MERGE (n: Object { object:nodeRecord.object }) 
on CREATE SET n.size = [ nodeRecord.size ] 
on CREATE SET n.color = [ nodeRecord.color ] 
on MATCH SET n.size = n.size + [ nodeRecord.size ] 
on MATCH SET n.color = n.color + [ nodeRecord.color ]
```

but the problem is it keeps on adding size and color irrespective to if if has already come

Comment: Please edit your question and put the exact output that you expect. Thanks

Comment: two nodes A and B. Two properties Size And Color. Value for Size property for node A should be (200,300), value for color property for node A should be (White, Black, Pink). Value for size property for node B should be (300) and value for color property for node B should be (White, Black). Hope this answers your question? I have a spreadsheet with thousands of records so trying to make generic code.

Comment: Just give one example with Node A and B, I cannot imagine what you are trying to explain.

Comment: I already coded something as below. LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myfile.csv" AS nodeRecord
MERGE (n: Object { object:nodeRecord.object })
on CREATE SET n.size = [ nodeRecord.size ]
on CREATE SET n.color = [ nodeRecord.color ]
on MATCH SET n.size = n.size + [ nodeRecord.size ]
on MATCH SET n.color = n.color + [ nodeRecord.color ] but the problem is it keeps on adding size and color irrespective to if if has already come.

Comment: I answered your SO question below. Hope it will be useful for you. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for giving details on your SO post.  You can use the APOC function to convert the list into unique values (toSet).  Below is the updated query that you can use.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myfile.csv" AS nodeRecord 
MERGE (n: Object { object:nodeRecord.object }) 
on CREATE SET n.size = [ nodeRecord.size ] 
on CREATE SET n.color = [ nodeRecord.color ] 
on MATCH SET n.size = apoc.convert.toSet(n.size + [ nodeRecord.size ]) 
on MATCH SET n.color = apoc.convert.toSet(n.color + [ nodeRecord.color ])

Result: 
MATCH (n:Object) Return n

Output:
╒════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"n"                                                                 │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"size":["200","300"],"color":["White","Black","Pink"],"object":"A"}│
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"size":["300"],"color":["White","Black"],"object":"B"}             │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Without using an APOC function, you can use a list function REDUCE. It will accumulate the values of your list and you can add a condition not to add a new value if it exists in the current list.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myfile.csv" AS nodeRecord 
MERGE (n: Object { object:nodeRecord.object }) 
on CREATE SET n.size = [ nodeRecord.size ] 
on CREATE SET n.color = [ nodeRecord.color ] 
on MATCH SET n.size = REDUCE(sz = [], element IN n.size+[nodeRecord.size] | CASE WHEN NOT element in sz THEN sz + element ELSE sz END)
on MATCH SET n.color = REDUCE(co = [], element IN n.color+[nodeRecord.color] | CASE WHEN NOT element in co THEN co + element ELSE co END)
```

Comment: Pls accept and upvote my answer. You will find the button on the left beside my answer.